# How to input Gregorian Calendar on application from Object Class using JOption

Tags: java, calendar

Object Class

```
public Association(String assoName, String Abbrv, GregorianCalendar formDate, Student president)
    {
        this.assoName = assoName;
        this.abbrv = abbrv;
        this.formDate = formDate;
        this.president = president;
    }
```

Application class

```
String assoName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Association Name: ");
pw.println(assoName);
String abbrv = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Association's Abbreviation");
pw.print(","+abbrv);
GregorianCalendar formDate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Association Formation Date (dd/mm/yyyy) ");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

Can you please help me with the program T_T
I cant change anything as it's for my project and it's already set by my professor.

Comment: The `GregorianCalendar` class has design problems and is now long outdated. You will obtain your desired result more easily with the modern `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, so do yourself the favour of changing over to them,

Comment: The application class code cannot be compiled due to errors. If you cannot change anything, does that mean you cannot fix those errors?

Comment: @OleV.V. how to change to LocalDate and DateTimeFormatter from GregorianCalender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to change to LocalDate and DateTimeFormatter from GregorianCalender?

If you can, change `GregorianCalendar formDate` to `LocalDate formDate` in the `Association` class.

In any case, the one-arg `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` that you use for reading the formation date from the user returns a `String`, so I suggest you read it into a `String` variable, say, `formationDateString`, and then parse it into a `LocalDate`. Something like:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/u");
    String formationDateString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Association Formation Date (dd/mm/yyyy) ");
    try {
        LocalDate formDate = LocalDate.parse(formationDateString, dateFormatter);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid date format",
                "id frn’s app", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

If you cannot change the `Association` constructor, convert your `LocalDate` to `GregorianCalendar` like this after parsing:

```
        ZonedDateTime startOfDay = formDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        GregorianCalendar formDateGregCal = GregorianCalendar.from(startOfDay);
```

If what you are saying is that your professor insists on using the badly designed and long outdated `GregorianCalendar` (not to mention the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`), you may want to check whether it’s OK to use the modern and far better alternative, though (and feel free to quote me here).